# Print with automatic tab (Python)

Tags: python, printing

Is there some simple command or way -- let's call it \magic -- so that having

```
print('Hello!\magicHello!')
```

produces the follwing

```
Hello!
      Hello!
```

That is, it makes the next line be indented precisely to the end of the previous?

Many thanks!

Comment: It looks like you just want print('Hello! Hello!'); at least that will print what is displayed in the question.  Maybe you need to edit the formatting of the question...

Comment: What are you printing *to*? A linux terminal? A curses screen? A Windows console?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry if it isn't displaying correctly. It should be one 'Hello' below another, beginning where the top one ends. It's showing fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that by wrapping string in function:

```
def magic(s):
    res, indent = [], 0
    for part in s.split('\magic'):
        res.append(' ' * indent + part)
        indent += len(part)
    return '\n'.join(res)

print magic('Hello!\magicHello!')
```

Which produces:

```
Hello!
      Hello!
```

Comment: This is wonderful! Thank you very much, it does precisely what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a tab character ("\t"), and there are various things that you can do with justification and padding, but I don't think that there's a way to get the precision you want without it being more cumbersome than the straightforward solution:

```
printstring = "Hello!"
print(printstring+"\n"+len(printstring)*" " + printstring)
```

EDIT:

If you have a list of words that you want to print this way, you can do the following:

```
words = ["This", "is", "a", "test"]
for i in range(len(words)):
    print(sum([len(w) for w in words[:i]])*" " + words[i])
```

It's a little cumbersome, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this dynamically, if I am not just working with the single word 'Hello'?

Comment: Like, you have a list of words and you want to print each one at the indentation level where the previous ended?

Comment: Yeah, but potentially a great many words, being taken from a database. Maybe I need to rethink how this should be done... ;)

Comment: Okay, the new edit should work for an arbitrarily long list... assuming you don't run out of space horizontally.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply. I guess this will work. I will just have to generate the list first, but that shouldn't be hard.